# Is there a way to unroll a proof (or environment) in LateX?

Tags: environments

In many papers I read or write, I would like to first skim or present a section with only the statements of the lemmata/claims/etc. to make the structure of the overall argument apparent, while in a second pass going over the details of each proof.

One way to allow a reader to do this would be to have a proof environment in the pdf, whose contents are hidden by default, but which "enroll" when the reader clicks on "proof."

Is that achievable in LaTeX?

Comment: pdf pages are rigid, contrarily to HTML, so your options are (1) to have some text that is initially hidden (but taking space on the page) and whose display can be toggled, or (2) having cross-links from a shot version to a longer version on another page.

Comment: It is really more a question of what you can do in PDF than what LaTeX can do. Though there is also the issue of what PDF viewers support. If you need this to work for many people (i.e. not just you), you'll struggle to make it work for everyone. (Links would work, but the hide/unhide stuff is going to be partly or wholly unsupported by some viewers. And even supported viewers will probably break it by default for security reasons.)

Comment: @cfr Mh. I'm unaware of what PDF does support. Maybe it'd make sense for me to rephrase the question as "can I achieve this in LateX, so that I can obtain the result above for *some* widespread export format (pdf, dvi, HTML...) supported by LateX"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Bruno's first option:

Here an approach with "Optional Content Groups" (OCGs). The packages used, like `aeb_pro`  and `eforms`,can be found on CTAN and are not part of the actual TL distribution.

The given button toggles the state of the OCG from "off" to "on" and back ...

**Note:** The workflow I used is: latex -> dvips -> distiller -> PDF and for proper PDF working, a JavaScript based PDF-Viewer is necessary (Adobe Reader works best).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage[uselayers]{aeb_pro}

\begin{document}
\pushButton[\CA{Press me to show proof}\autoCenter{n}\A{\JS{toggleSetThisLayer("myToggle");}}]{myBtn}{5cm}{12bp}

\xBld{myToggle}%
Here comes some text that might span over multiple lines
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2
\]
\eBld
\end{document}
```

See screenshots:

[image]
[image]